# About magento2 performce-test-toolkit

Tags: magento2, performance

I want to test magento2.0.4 performance in my virtual machine .
I read Magento Performance Toolkit User Guide.pdf in https://github.com/magento/magento-performance-toolkit .
It teach me that The most recent version of the Magento Performance Toolkit for 2.x is published at https://github.com/magento/magento2 and included in the /dev/tools/performance_toolkit folder.

So I downloaded magento2.0.4 but there isn't /dev/tools/performance_toolkit forlder.

I want to try this one .
I want to know how performance when cart in and check out .

Answer (score 0):

You can now find it under /setup.

Magento 2: https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/setup/performance-toolkit
Magento 1: https://github.com/magento/magento-performance-toolkit

Also see http://www.magemeter.com/